# After upgrading to 12.04 from 10.10 my mythbuntu standard MCEUSB remote no longer works

Tags: 12.04, mythbuntu, remote-control, lirc

I had no problems using my Windows Media Center Remote with 10.10 Mythbuntu, but after upgrading, it no longer affects Mythbuntu.

I have verified and re-installed it in Mythbuntu Control Centre.

I have used `irw` to verify the ir buttons actions are properly received by the HTPC.

How do I go about fixing this?

---

3.2.0-26-generic (#41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012)
Xorg version: 1.11.3 (16 July 2012  08:06:31PM)
GCC: 4.6 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
Current updates as of 2012‧07‧21

---

```
$cat /etc/lirc/hardware.con

#Chosen Remote Control
REMOTE="Windows Media Center Transceivers/Remotes (all)"
REMOTE_MODULES="lirc_dev mceusb"
REMOTE_DRIVER=""
REMOTE_DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
REMOTE_SOCKET=""
REMOTE_LIRCD_CONF="mceusb/lircd.conf.mceusb"
REMOTE_LIRCD_ARGS=""

#Chosen IR Transmitter
TRANSMITTER="None"
TRANSMITTER_MODULES=""
TRANSMITTER_DRIVER=""
TRANSMITTER_DEVICE=""
TRANSMITTER_SOCKET=""
TRANSMITTER_LIRCD_CONF=""
TRANSMITTER_LIRCD_ARGS=""

#Enable lircd
START_LIRCD="true"

#Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
#START_LIRCMD="false"

#Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES="true"

# Default configuration files for your hardware if any
LIRCMD_CONF=""

#Forcing noninteractive reconfiguration
#If lirc is to be reconfigured by an external application
#that doesn't have a debconf frontend available, the noninteractive
#frontend can be invoked and set to parse REMOTE and TRANSMITTER
#It will then populate all other variables without any user input
#If you would like to configure lirc via standard methods, be sure
#to leave this set to "false"
FORCE_NONINTERACTIVE_RECONFIGURATION="false"
    START_LIRCMD=""


# lsusb | grep -i infrared
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0471:0815 Philips (or NXP) eHome Infrared Receiver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for me I found that editing the .mythtv/lircrc file was the answer. I had to append a "key_" in front of all the button = keyname lines.

e.g button = Up becomes button = key_Up

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response...  I'd forgotten about this question.  The "cure" for me turned out to just to "touch" the files.  Inexplicable. The problem was "worked" out here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2031835&highlight=keepitsimpleengr